# Can not get list object which have one-to-many relationship in hibernate using mysql

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have schema below:
Customer
id -Primary key
customer_name
phone
.............

Service
 id -Primary key
customer_id -- foreign key to Customer.id
 .................

Customer.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="thesis.database.Customer" table="customer">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
    </meta>
    <id name="customerId" type="int" column="customer_id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
<property name="phone" column="phone" type="string" />
    <bag name="services" table="use_service" inverse="false" fetch="join" lazy="false"
        cascade="all">
        <key column="customer_id"  />
        <one-to-many class="thesis.database.Service" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

Service.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="thesis.database.Service" table="service">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the Service detail.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="customer" class="thesis.database.Customer"
        fetch="select">
        <column name="customer_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>

    ....................

</class>
```

My function

```
 public static Customer getCustomerByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    Session session = getSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Customer.class);
    Criterion phone = Restrictions.eq("phone", phoneNumber);
    criteria.add(phone);
    Customer customer = (Customer) criteria.uniqueResult();
    session.close();
    return customer;
}
```

And after that, i call

```
Customer customer =  getCustomerByPhoneNumber("123456789"); // customer with this phone is availuable in database
```

I get this customer normally, but i cell getServices() function to get list service, it always get the same list, although i try to add more records to service table.

For example:
Customer table
id customer_name  phone ................
1  Mr A           123456789................

and service table
id customer_id ........................
1   1          ........................
2   1          ........................
3   1          ........................

First query. i got list size = 3;
after insert one more record like that 4   1  ............ to service table
Second query. i also got list size = 3;

Can everybody tell me why and suggest any solution? thank in advance!

My solution is using Transaction to commit after adding new record.

Comment: Please do not tag JPA problems with JSF. Only when you have problems with classes from `javax.faces.*` package or with tags from `http://java.sun.com/jsf/*` URI, then you've a JSF problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are forgetting to execute the criteria. Here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html they are always calling the list method.

Comment: Sorry, i posted wrong function, i have already edited, any another solution?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. I used to write annotations instead of xml. You can check to do the same query inside of the method, before closing the session. If the data is correct there is a problem with the session, if the data is not correct then the problem is another one.

Comment: ok, thank so much, now i know what solution is, I have to use Transaction to commit after adding new record. Because i studied some tutorials on the internet, but authors did not use Transaction with criteria. Thank again